# Как сделать чтобы при рассылке, бот удалял пользователей которые его заблокировали?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, бот, python-telegram-bot

Нужно чтобы при рассылке, бот удалял пользователей которые заблокировали бота.

```
while int(i) < int(int(len(barge)) - 1):
                        try:
                            keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
                            keyboard.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Получить скидку",
                                            url="https://deepnuder.xyz/shop.php?user=" + barge[i][12] + "&id=" + str(
                                                barge[i][2])))
                            bot.send_message(barge[i][2], us[0][0], parse_mode="MARKDOWN", reply_markup=keyboard)
                        except:
                            pass
                        i = i + 1
                        print(barge[i][2])
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте `try/except`

```
  for user_id in user_id_list:
        try:
            await bot.send_message(user_id, msg)
            logger.debug(f'CONSOLE - {user_id} user successfully notified')
        except exceptions.BotBlocked:
            db.remove_user_from_db(user_id)
            logger.debug(f'CONSOLE - {user_id} user stopped bot')
```